# Documentation on usage of brackets() in mysql queries

Tags: mysql

I have an application where i am needed to write queries with multiple conditions and i am using several other keywords such as `between`, `and`, `or` etc

I have this two conditions

`select * from countries where date between (x and y) and filter = filter and column choosen like '%col%';`

and

`select * from countries where date between (x and y) and filter = filter`

I haven't actually run the queries but i want the date condition using `between` to be executed first and i thought the brackets would help.

What is the exact usage of brackets `()` in mysql and where is that documented?.

Comment: Brackets have the highest priority. The rest can be found there: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Operator Precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html).

Comment: I am actually on that page.  The reason i am even asking is i have a condition of multiple between statements and i am wondering if the brackets indicate precedence then what becomes the order of execution.

Comment: Cool. I also have a `name like %%` so i can put  this inside the where as well and not outside of it?

Comment: The best way is to put all possible brackets. And you'll not need to think what's before and what's after...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting parentheses in a `BETWEEN` leads to strangenesses:

```
date between (x and y) and filter1 = filter2
```

is treated as

```
(date between (x and y) and filter1) = filter2
```

Why?

- `BETWEEN` expects 2 'arguments'; you have given it (1) `(x and y)`, which returns true or false, which are numerically 1 or 0, and `filter1`.
- The result of that (probably 0) is then compared:  `0 = filter`, which is likely to be false (0).

Recommendations:

- Do not use parens *that way* in `BETWEEN`.  These are OK:

  ```
  (date between x and y)

  (date) between (x) and (y)  -- but this is clutter
  ```
- When mixing `AND` and `OR` use parens to make it clear what you want to do.  `AND` will be done before `OR`, but too many SQL programmers fail know that, so be explicit:

  ```
  a AND (b OR c)  -- Without parens, you get  (a AND b) OR c

  x = 1 AND ( y = 2 OR z = 3 )
  ```
- Don't clutter:  Rarely do you need `(x)` instead lf `x`.
- When in doubt, add parens, even if it clutters.
- When using function calls, no space before the `(`; there are cases where the parser decides whether it is a function call versus something else by using that spacing:  `DATE(foo)`, not `DATE (foo)`.

The documentation spells all of this out, but not necessarily in an obvious way.  Here are clues:

- The `BETWEEN` syntax does *not* show the parens you asked about.
- Any expression can have parens around it.
- There is a "precedence" that says what happens when mixing `AND` and `OR` -- which is just like `*` and `+`.  (You do understand that `1+2*3` is `7`, not `9` because `*` is evaluated before `+`?)

Answer (score -1):

Brackets have the highest priority.

```sql
-- original
select * from countries where date between (x and y) and filter = filter and choosen like '%col%';
-- step 1
select * from countries where date between (x and y) and filter = filter and (choosen like '%col%');
-- step 2
select * from countries where (date between (x and y) and filter) = filter and (choosen like '%col%');
-- step 3
select * from countries where ((date between (x and y) and filter) = filter) and (choosen like '%col%');
-- finally
select * from countries where (((date between (x and y) and filter) = filter) and (choosen like '%col%'));
```

```sql
-- original
select * from countries where date between (x and y) and filter = filter
-- step 1
select * from countries where (date between (x and y) and filter) = filter
-- finally
select * from countries where ((date between (x and y) and filter) = filter)
```

Comment: why is this `and filter) = filter`, that looks out of place.

Comment: @Gandalf `BETWEEN` priority is up to `= (comparison)` priority. So in `a BETWEEN b AND c = d` the first step is `a BETWEEN b AND c`, not `c = d`.

Comment: is this correct `select * from countries where ((date between (x and y)) and (filter = filter) and (choosen like '%col%'));`

Comment: @Gandalf No. `(date between (x and y))` == `(date between Z)` - no AND, syntax error. Correctly: `select * from countries where ((date between (x and y) and (filter = filter)) and (choosen like '%col%'))`. Synthactically correct, of course, nothing about logical correctness.

Comment: @Gandalf Execution order: `(x and y) => A` `(filter = filter) => B` `(date between A and B) => C` `(choosen like '%col%') => D` `C and D => result`.

Comment: In `select * from countries where (((date between (x and y) and filter) = filter) and (choosen like '%col%'));` if i were to have a second `filter2 = filter2`, where would that go.

Comment: @Gandalf Everything is dependent by the logic which you need to realize.

Comment: That was my entire question.Where is the formation of the logic using the brackets discussed in detail?. So far no where. Its not straight forward as you may think,one because, the queries may be syntax error free but still doesnt return the logically correct results.

Comment: This is more confusing than i thought. hang on, i am describing my question better on stackoverflow along side a form one can relate to.

Comment: I don't think the parens are valid in `date between (x and y)`.

Comment: @RickJames We now look brackets validity only, not datatypes - `date between (x and y) and z` is synthactically valid.